# Ajax Post Bad request with multiple parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

My Data parameter looks like below:

```
 data: '{"originfieldTitle":"' + $("#txt-central-name").val() + '","newfieldTitle":"' + $("#txt-local-name").val() + '","originfieldcolumn":"' + $("#txt-central-columnname").val() + '","countryId":"' + $("#business-drop-selected").val() + '"}',
```

And in WCF service the mthod looks like:

```
 [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SaveMapping", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public PortalResponse SaveMapping(string originfieldTitle, string newfieldTitle, string originfieldcolumn,  string countryId)
    {
    }
```

But I am getting always bad request in ajax it going into error callback.
When I send one parameter I can see the data in debug mode in wcf.
Can anyone please suggest ?I think some problem in data being sent,may bemissing comma.

AJAX

---

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: '{"originfieldTitle":"' + $("#txt-central-name").val() + '","newfieldTitle":"' + $("#txt-local-name").val() + '","originfieldcolumn":"' + $("#txt-central-columnname").val() + '","countryId":"' + $("#business-drop-selected").val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (!response.HasError) {
                        StaplesAca.UnLockUi();
                        MappingTableAdvanced.Reload();
                        MappingFeatures.ClearNewFormData();
                    } else {
                        bootbox.alert("Something went wrong. Please try again later! Error: " + response.Message);
                        StaplesAca.UnLockUi();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    bootbox.alert("Something went wrong. Please try again later!");
                    StaplesAca.UnLockUi();
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is your ajax method? How does it look like? Can you post that?

Comment: `processData: false,` why do you have this, it can be removed.

Comment: No removed it..Still same problem

Comment: can you try one thing instead of fetching data directly fetch before like var originfieldTitle = $("#txt-central-name").val() and give this variable name originfieldTitle when you are providing data attribute to ajax. Also make sure to debug that you are getting all four values before passing it to ajax

Comment: you can also try hard coded values like use this data: '{"originfieldTitle":"Test","newfieldTitle":"Test1","originfieldcolumn":"Test2","countryId":"Test3"}',       By doing this we can be closer to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Hey as your receiver is having BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
hence it should be a wrapped request please use data param in ajax like below :

```
data: JSON.stringify({originfieldTitle: $("#txt-central-name").val(),newfieldTitle: $("#txt-local-name").val() ,originfieldcolumn: $("#txt-central-columnname").val()
         ,countryId: $("#business-drop-selected").val()}),
```